# Rails caching on Heroku acting strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, heroku

I've implemented fragment caching on a view. More specifically on the comments section. It looks something like:

```
<% cache "video_#{@video.id}_comments" do %>
  <div id="comments">

    <%= render :partial => 'artists/videos/comments/comments' %>

  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my comment controller, create action, I have:

```
  ....
  if @comment.save
    expire_fragment("#{@comment.commentable.class.to_s.downcase}_#{@comment.commentable.id}_comments")
```

In development, when a new comment is created. The cache is expired and when I reload the page, the new comment displays normally.

On Heroku, this is not the case. Is it because I should be using memcache? Or am I doing something wrong elsewhere?

Comment: You realise the cache key in your view, and the one you are trying to expire are different?

Comment: How so? `"#{@comment.commentable.class.to_s.downcase}_#{@comment.commentable.id}_comments"` translates to `video_41_comments`

Comment: what cache store are you using in production?

Comment: No cache store set. config/environments/production.rb has it commented: `# config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store`

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, My bad, didnt read the whole thing :)

Comment: @dexter you are right! If I have several web dynos running, and I refresh the page. Sometimes the comment will show and sometimes it won't

Comment: Do you recommend the memcache or the memcachier addon?

Comment: @dexter adding a cache store solved the issue. If you have it as an answer, I will gladly select it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea. Can you try:

```
Rails.cache.delete("views/"#{@comment.commentable.class.to_s.downcase}_#{@comment.commentable.id}_comments")
```

in the place of expire_fragment

Also, I strongly suggest using a cache store in heroku. Else, the default is **memory store which is local to a dyno and not visible to other dynos**. Also, your application memory will run out soon. Also, the dalli store provided by Heroku is super fast. Refer this [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache)